# Why does the same code for Java and PHP not work?

Tags: java, php, recursion, generator

I wrote a program in PHP and Java which generates all possible words with length 2. 
I used recursion.
Why does the program work in Java but not in PHP? It's the same code.

**Java**

```
package com.company;


public class Words {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    generate("", 2);
}

static void generate(String prefix, int remainder) {
    if (remainder == 0) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    } else {
        for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
            generate(prefix + c, remainder - 1);
        }
    }
}
}
```

**PHP**

```
generate('', 2);

function generate($prefix, $remainder)
{
if ($remainder == 0) {
    echo "$prefix\n";
} else {
    for ($c = 'A'; $c <= 'Z'; $c++) {
        generate($prefix . $c, $remainder - 1);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What does `PHP` program prints for the given input?

Comment: I am not familiar what the first line in php does the generate, and have you declared variables? Are you working in a .php file. I do not have much to work with here, i am just trying to see if you looked at the basics

Comment: In PHP: It prints all possible words until length 4. And then it stops at  YZYZ. But it should stop at ZZ

Comment: Well your code works, I tried it on http://www.writephponline.com/ and had this output: https://i.imgur.com/zgtaxj4.png

Comment: Yes but it should stop at ZZ. Just like Java did. But it does not stop.

Comment: Update your question and post the `Java` output and the `PHP` output

Comment: Don't use `<=` when comparing strings like that.... By an alphabetic comparison, `AA` is always less than `Z` (aaron comes before zedekiah in the phone book, doesn't it).... compare using `!== AA` instead of `<= Z`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`$c` has string type in PHP. The `++` operator works differently for it compared to numbers.

PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl `$a = 'Z'; $a++;` turns `$a` into `'AA'`, while in C `a = 'Z'; a++;` turns a into `'['` *(ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91)*. Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: At least this answer explains what's going on, instead of just posting some working code and nothing more!

Answer (score 6):

Change your loop from

```
for ($c = 'A'; $c <= 'Z'; $c++) {
```

to

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $c){
```

============================

**EDIT**:

Sorry, I tried to find an official document about this, but I cannot. So I'll try to explain a little

In php, when you compare 2 strings, the system wil try to compare the first character and then the second ..... the compare operator will be stop when the first different character appear

Example

```
$a = 'ABCDEZ';
$b = 'ABCEZZ';
```

String $b greater than $a because the value ABC in the beginning of $a and $b is the same but E (the value in index 3 of string $b) greater than D (the value in index 3 of string $a), and they don't need to compare other characters

In this question, the original loop is

```
for ($c = 'A'; $c <= 'Z'; $c++) {
```

it's fine until $c = 'Z', but after that $c++ will be 'AA' and when php start to compare it, 'AA' < 'Z' and the loop continue, that's why I changed the loop  to

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $c){
```

To make it work

**I hope you enjoy it and happy with my explain, sorry because I don't see any document about this, it's just how php work and I know it**

Comment: Would you like to explain why your answer solves the problem?

Comment: SO is not really meant to be a coding service. If you answer a question, try to educate the OP as to what's happening. Don't just post some code and nothing else!

Comment: I updated my answer, sorry for took it so long to explain